Replace OpenAI Assistant File Citations with Sequential Reference Numbers using AI SDK
I'm building a NuxtJS application using Vercel's AI SDK to interact with OpenAI's Assistants API. When the assistant references files in its responses, it generates citations in this format: 【4:2†Source】.
I need to replace these random citation markers (e.g. 4:2†) with sequential footnote references (e.g. 1, [2], etc.) so users can easily map citations to references.
Here's my current setup using the useAssistant hook:
const { messages, append } = useAssistant({
  api: '/api/assistant'
});

The messages are rendered like this:
<template>
  <div v-for="message in messages" :key="message.id">
    {{ message.content }}
  </div>
</template>

Sample output:
According to the document 【4:2†Source】, the deadline is tomorrow. The budget information in 【7:1†Source】 shows...

Desired output:
According to the document [1], the deadline is tomorrow. The budget information in [2] shows...

References:
[1] file name title
[2] file name title from

I believe I need to:

Intercept the assistant's response
Use regex to find and replace the citation format
Build a references list from file retrieval by id
Update the message content

Where in the Vercel AI SDK's AssistantResponse flow should I implement this transformation? Should I modify the message content when appending new messages or create a computed property for displaying the transformed content?
What I've tried:
I've looked through the AI SDK documentation but haven't found clear guidance on message content transformation. I considered using a computed property but worry about maintaining the reference list state across messages.
Any help would be appreciated!
Full code:
      // Create and handle the assistant response stream
      const response = AssistantResponse(
        { threadId, messageId: createdMessage.id },
        async ({ forwardStream }) => {
          // Get both the run stream and message stream
          const stream = openai.beta.threads.runs
            .stream(threadId, {
              assistant_id: assistantId,

              // Add include parameter to get file search results
              include: [
                'step_details.tool_calls[*].file_search.results[*].content'
              ],
              // https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/assistants/modifyAssistant
              tools: [
                {
                  type: 'file_search',
                  file_search: {
                    ranking_options: {
                      //  a ranking between 0.0 and 1.0, with 1.0 being the highest ranking. A higher number will constrain the file chunks used to generate a result to only chunks with a higher possible relevance, at the cost of potentially leaving out relevant chunks.
                      score_threshold: 0.5,
                      ranker: 'auto'
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            })
            .on('messageDelta', (event) => {
              const content = event.content?.[0]
              if (content?.type === 'text' && content.text?.value != null) {
                console.log('content: ', content)
              }
            })
            .on('messageDone', async (event) => {
              // Add this code to fetch and log run steps
              try {
                const run = await openai.beta.threads.runs.steps.list(
                  threadId,
                  event.run_id
                )
                // Find the step with tool_calls
                const toolCallStep = run.data.find(
                  (step) => step.type === 'tool_calls'
                )
                console.log(
                  'toolCallStep: ',
                  toolCallStep.step_details.tool_calls[0].file_search.results
                )
              } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching run steps:', error)
              }

              if (event.content[0].type === 'text') {
                const { text } = event.content[0]
                if (text.annotations) {
                  const citationsText = text.annotations.map((annotation) => {
                    return `[${annotation.text}] (${annotation.file_citation.file_id})`
                  })
                  // Join citationsText with two new lines
                  citationsText.join('\n\n')

                  res.write(
                    formatAssistantStreamPart(
                      'text',
                      '\n\n### Citations\n' + citationsText
                    )
                  )
                }
                console.log(
                  'event content text annotations: ',
                  event.content[0].text.annotations
                )
              }
            })

          await forwardStream(stream)
        }
      )

      // Get the stream from the Response object
      const stream = response.body

      // Set appropriate headers for streaming
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
        'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
      })

      // Pipe the stream to the response
      if (stream) {
        for await (const chunk of stream) {
          res.write(chunk)
        }
      }

      res.end()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Assistant error:', error)
      res.status(500).send({
        error:
          'An error occurred while processing your request in assistant function.',
        details: error.message
      })
    }

